# PHP echo `null` values

Tags: null, xampp, wampserver

I recently ported from XAMPP, to the latest WAMP Version. All the codes from the previous server work fine, in particular, displaying Null values.

```
In XAMPP:

echo $a;

If $a is not yet declared, the system just prints nothing.
```

However,

```
in WAMP

echo $a;

If $a is not yet declared, the system gives an error `Undefined Variable`.
```

I checked my php.ini configuration files and httpd.conf but still, I can't get the new version to display the null values.

QUESTION:

**Is there anyway in the config to make php display the null values without declaring it or anything?**

PS:
the XAMPP we use is 1.7.3
the WAMP i use now is 2.2e

Please do help. Thank you. :-)

Comment: I think that it returns you a notice or warning so you have to switch off displaying errors `ini_set('display_errors','Off');`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I found out that the error came from another php.ini file located at 
"C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\bin\php.ini". For anyone who encounters errors such as this, check you phpinfo() for the path of the php.ini file the server is using. :-) Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its probably a PHP setting for the PHP error level.

PHP only shows undefined variables when PHP Notices are enabled.

XAMPP probably doesn't enable PHP notices by default whereas WAMP most likely does.

To make WAMP not output undefined variable, open php.ini and change 'error_reporting' to:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

This should tell PHP to output all errors except notices.

Answer (score 1):

Your WAMP setup will be configured to display Errors & Notices see http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

This is good practice for development, you should also declare your variables first, or check that they are initiated before manipulating them

for example      :

```
echo isset($a) ? $a : NULL;
```

PHP is throwing an error for reason and these should not simply be ignored. If you do you will end up with problems, not to mention huge error log files.